# How to consume wcf service in servicenow tool?

Tags: c#, wcf, servicenow

I had created one WCF service(http://xyz/userdisable.svc), and hosted in windows server.While consuming this service in Servicenow tool I'm getting below exception.

> Unable to load WSDL: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused):java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused)

I also tried to consume this service in console application it works fine,

My web.config looks like,

```
<system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="UserDisablebehaviour" name="UserDisableWeb.UserDisableService">
          <endpoint address="http://xyz/userdisable.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="UserDisableWeb.UserDisableService" />
        </service>
      </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="UserDisablebehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Do I missing any settings in web.config ?

Comment: are you sure the port 80 on xyz is open to the servicenow world?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I create web service not a wcf then it works find in servicenow, is it still issue of port ?

Comment: Sometimes wcf runs on another port.. so yes could be

Comment: I found that we need to do some changes at servicenow to consume wcf service